# How does Kest kill the Saint of Swords?

Tags: greatcoats

In Traitor's Blade by Sebastien de Castell the character Kest kills the Saint of Swords near the end of the book. However the fight itself is not described in the book.

Before the fight the main character whispers a tip to Kest and after the fight Kest says the tip worked. But as far as I remember the tip is not mentioned.

> Kest grabbed me by the shoulders and looked me in the eyes. He looked crazed. ‘Falcio, I need you to do something for me.’
>   ‘Anything,’ I said.
>   ‘You beat me – that one time at the castle, you beat me. Tell me how you did it. Maybe I can … maybe there’s something I haven’t tried, something I haven’t seen, or some technique—’
>   My heart fell. I could have lain down on the ground and simply let the Saint kill me, or the Duke’s army run right over me, or any of a hundred other deaths that awaited me. For my whole life Kest had been like the mountains or the oceans or the sky: he feared nothing and was angered by nothing. Everything was simply interesting to him – and now he was going mad.
>   **I put my hands on his shoulders and whispered into his ear, and I told him how I had beaten him that day at Castle Aramor.** And when I was done, I kissed him on the forehead and said goodbye.
>   He gave me a little smile for a second and said, ‘Well now, I don’t think that’s going to work here, is it? But I suppose anything’s worth trying once.’

Comment: The title may be considered a spoiler - I was curious about how to deal with this, but there's a few threads [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/835/is-it-okay-to-have-spoilers-in-question-titles) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229614/possible-spoilers-in-the-title-and-what-to-do-about-it) which seem to say it's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't find out until the final novel, [Tyrant's Throne](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30317594-tyrant-s-throne) how he beat Caveil, by catching him off-guard with a smutty joke.

> *Kest shrugged. ‘Right before I was to fight Caveil, when I asked you how you’d beaten me in the fencing match to become First Cantor, you told me you’d fooled me into using my own reflexes against myself. Of course, I didn’t exactly have time to trick Caveil into making his muscles memorise the necessary reactions.’ He shook his head. ‘He was so fast, Falcio. I could barely even see his blade moving. Every time I tried to thrust at him, he just batted away my sword before the tip had moved even an inch. There was no way I could win in a fair fight.’
>   ‘So you . . . ?’
>
>   ‘Even as he was cutting me to ribbons, Caveil was boasting about the price you and Brasti and the others would pay for my arrogance in challenging him. He was describing the things he’d do to you all – he started saying, “I’ll use their stiffened corpses as decorations in my home” – and then . . . just when he was going to deliver the final blow . . .’ Kest looked down and leaned his head against the bars. ‘Please don’t ever tell Brasti about this. You have to promise . . .’
>
>   ‘Why not?’
>
>   **‘Because at that exact moment I found myself remembering the punchline to that joke Brasti always tells – about three lonely nuns and a dead cleric? You know the one: “Be careful where you sit, sister, or you’ll be committing a mortal sin”—’**
>
>   The snort that came out my nose nearly set the bars of my cell shaking. ‘And Caveil?’
>
>   Kest looked up and I could see tears in his eyes from trying to hold back the laughter. **‘He was so shocked – he tried not to laugh, and he just stood there frozen. It was only an instant – less than half a second – but in that time I got the point of my sword into line and—’
>
>   ‘You killed the Saint of Swords, the greatest fencer alive, with a dirty joke.’***

Comment: "*Based on a very quick read-through of the novel, it would appear*" - so you don't actually know the books or the characters? :-)

Comment: @Randal'thor - Not in the slightest. But the incident is pretty solidly signposted in the scene the OP is talking about and there doesn't *seem* to be any further mention of their fight elsewhere in the novel

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Ah, the benefits of reading on...

Comment: Ha, I *thought* it'd be answered in some throwaway scene in a later book!

Comment: Brilliant! I was worried it was going to be left unanswered.